# Visual Studio 2015 not recognizing Ionic and angularjs parameters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

After 4 days searching intensely about why my Visual Studio is not recognizing the ionic html tags and AngularJS parameters, I came here to find the answer and can help others too.

- Installed Visual Studio Community 2015 - Update 3
- Installed Apache Cordova tools for Visual Studio
- Installed Node.js 64 Bits (v6.3.1)
- Installed Ionic on npm: "npm install -g cordova ionic"
- Created a Ionic project on console: "ionic start myProjectName"
- Converted in a Visual Studio Solution (Project from existing code).
- First build downloaded rest of the things.
- Opened a ionic html and:

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

P.S: I don't use Resharper, and I installed the Ionic Pack from Extensions and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER FOUND**

Worked for me:

Delete the Visual Studio folder from app data

- C:\Users\ (yourusername)\AppData\Roaming\Visual Studio

This will reset your Visual Studio style, configs and caches.